# JBPM sample application without Database

Tags: jboss, jbpm

Can I develop a JBPM sample application without using any relational database.? Is the relational database mandatory or can I use some other mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

jBPM persistence layer uses the [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) for persistence ( Hibernate implementation ) and JPA is for relational data.

If your scope allows for a customization of jBPM persistence module you may be able to do it as the data objects has a clean abstraction.

Check [Data nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DataNucleus) is a fully compliant implementation of the Java Data Objects specification, which allows datastores  other than relational ones.